# sfDoctrineGuardPlugin + vjCommentPlugin

Tags: symfony1, sfdoctrineguard

I'll have installed both plugins on my symfony project via official Readme, everything installed fine, without errors.
But when I click on SendComment button, I have error:

```
Empty module and/or action after parsing the URL
```

But when I place cursor to the address bar and press enter, page refresh and I can see my page but without comments(link is right) (my database is empty too).
Can you help my please?
My submit form:

```
<?php if( vjComment::checkAccessToForm() ): ?>
  <form action="" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add new comment', array(), 'vjComment') ?></legend>
    <?php include_partial("comment/form", array('form' => $form)) ?>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your routing, and enable post method. This worked for me.

```
sf_method: [get, post]
```